Document wide table heading rotation
We use Markdown and pandoc to main a large'ish corpus of documents.
Pandoc uses LaTeX as an intermediate format when exporting Markdown documents as pdf.
As such, there is no way to apply formatting directly to individual LaTeX tables, as we maintain the documents in Markdown.
For various reasons, we would like to rotate all table headings in the generated LaTeX by 90 degress to reduce their width.
Pandoc supports injecting LaTeX document header commands. We currently use this to set page orientation, margins and a few other things.
So, the question is, is it possible to inject a set of LaTeX header commands which rotate all table headings by 90 degress, without modifying individual tables?
An example of LaTeX generated by Pandoc is included below:

\title{Hello}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
Cell 1 & Cell 2\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Does this answer your question? How to make table with rotated table headers in LaTeX

@Fran and the other duplicate voter(s): I don't think, that this is really a duplicate, because the question here IMHO is, how to do the rotation from within the document preamble without changing the generated table code. But the answers to the linked questions need changes of the table code, e.g., adding commands like \rot or change to the usage of NiceTabular.

@cabohah I think you are right, but as pandoc can only export markdown tables to longtable, the only solution could be change how the package longtable works, that I guessed  that this is hard project. On th othe hand, the table in markdown can include latex commands, so if you can use \rot{foo} in a longtable cell in latex, you can do also in a markdown table without touch later the generated latex table. Let the interlocutor clarify if he can handle with that.
